# Different "clickable" log items in Chorome Dev Tools console

Tags: console, formatting, google-chrome-devtools

When I `console.log` a javascript object or array in Chrome Dev Tools I get a nice and clickable "drilldown" tree representation where I can inspect the various values, their keys and values with all the syntax highlighting, (i) icon, `.length` shown etc.

[image]

**Is there some extension API for doing/changing this behaviour so it is different for some other classes/instances?** *My idea was to format Clojure data structures so one can inspect them the same way.*

EDIT: I know I can do a simple formatting in `console.log` via `%c` etc., but that is only a tiny fraction of what I want to do.

So far I wasn't successful with googling. If you know where is the correct Chrome extension API written, can you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no current extension APIs for customizing console output. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142783 tracks that item. The team is open to a patch for this, if you'd like to look into tackling the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to override `console.log` and, when object you are interested in is being printed out, use own function for printing it. To achieve something similar to the default object output you should probably use `console.group` and console text formatting (shown bellow).

[image: console text formatting]
[image: console grouping]

[See the official docs for more tips on using the Console.](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)